# How to run shell script from aws ECS operator

Tags: airflow, operators, google-cloud-dataflow, amazon-ecs

I have runcustomscript.sh inside my container (abs path: /opt/scripts/runcustomscript.sh) and I want to execute it through ECS operator:

```
EcsRunTaskOperator(
  ...
  overrides={
    "containerOverrides": [{
        "name": CONTAINER_NAME,
        "command": [
            "runcustomscript.sh",
            "input1" "foo",
            "input2", "bar"
        ]
    }]
  }
)
```

I have three questions:

1. How can I provide the path to script to the operator to ensure that it can access it within the container?
2. my script needs two inputs. If I add them as above, can script access it? (same as when we execute an script from the command line an pass command line args)
3. when the script generates non-zero exit code, how can I ensure that my ecs operator captures that?